# How to change Bazel build output directory location

Tags: build, bazel

I have small project and after building it he layout looks like this.

```
|-- BUILD
|-- README.md
|-- VERSION
|-- WORKSPACE
|-- bazel-bin -> /home/bkch/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bkch/172376ca1288bc6e93208fc2d53c0b74/execroot/distroless/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin
|-- bazel-distroless -> /home/bkch/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bkch/172376ca1288bc6e93208fc2d53c0b74/execroot/distroless
|-- bazel-out -> /home/bkch/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bkch/172376ca1288bc6e93208fc2d53c0b74/execroot/distroless/bazel-out
|-- bazel-testlogs -> /home/bkch/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bkch/172376ca1288bc6e93208fc2d53c0b74/execroot/distroless/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs
|-- debian_archives.bzl
```

`bazel-bin, bazel-out, bazel-distroless, bazel-testlogs` are symbolic links to `.cache` in user root folder. Instead of the symbolic links I would like to build them in current workspace directory.

From the [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/command-line-reference.html#flag--output_base) I tried using `--output_base=$PWD/output or --output_user_root=$PWD/output` . The moment I use these options the `bazel build` is failing of various random reasons. But when I use `bazel build //...` with out these options the build succeeds.

[image]

Comment: I guess the answer might lie here...  https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/13601
we just need to have  folder outside the project folder  --output_base=$PWD/../output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the answer might lie here... [github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/13601](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/13601) we just need to have folder outside the project folder --output_base=$PWD/../output